# Measuring how long PostgreSQL waits for locks

Tags: postgresql, performance, locking, concurrency, metadata

I want to figure out how long PostgreSQL spends waiting for locks during a period of time (during this period of time, many requests are served by PostgreSQL).

#### What I know

PostgreSQL system table `pg_locks` show some information. Like:

```sql
SELECT * FROM 
    pg_locks         pl   LEFT JOIN 
    pg_stat_activity psa
ON pl.pid = psa.pid;
```

But I still cannot figure out how long it spends on locks.

#### Why I am asking this question

I find when I increase the concurrency of PostgreSQL, (e.g., increase parallel worker per gather, max parallel workers or some other configurations), my 100-second multi-threaded TPC-C-like workload gets slower (i.e., lower throughput). So I want to figure out if this is because of too much contention.

#### Similar answer

For SQL Server: [How can I view how long a query has spent waiting for locks, without a profiler?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/117599)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enable `log_lock_waits` to get information about sessions that have to wait more than `deadlock_timeout` for a lock. You can reduce `deadlock_timeout` to see shorter waits.

Other than that, monitor the `wait_event_type` and `wait_event` in `pg_stat_activity`. If you see locks regularly, that can be a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I prefer `pg_stat_activity`way, but I find that it only shows the current status, while cannot record them persistently and let me know something like "how many wait events happen during the last 10 seconds?" @Albe

Comment: `pg_stat_activity` only shows what's going on right now. Historical data can only be got from the log.