# What could block a SELECT (read) in postgres

Tags: postgresql, blocking

I have a few long running transacrions that both select and update data. When the jobs are running, I suddently cannot run a basic SELECT + JOIN query on the table? It simply hangs forever... I thought mvcc would allow me to always read from the tables? (its fine to see the old version of the data). I'm not sure if the query is blocked or just slowed down (to the extreme) when the jobs are running.

I use the default read commited transaction level. pg 13.

Theories:

- Has the query become extremly slow because I'm updating data in the table concurrently, and mvcc has to keep track of which version of each row the query should see?
- Could it be because there are no more pg connections left in the connection pool for the SELECT query to run?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Measuring how long PostgreSQL waits for locks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/294363/measuring-how-long-postgresql-waits-for-locks)

Comment: Check pg_stat_activity and pg_lock to find out what the query is waiting for. Maybe an uncommitted DDL on the tables involved.

Comment: Connection pool is managed on the application side. You should be able to see (e.g. by taking a thread dump) whether your app hangs on the `select` statement or on acquiring a connection from the pool.

Comment: MVCC still has strong table locks, it is just that ordinary INSERT and UPDATE operations don't need to take them.  Other things still do, though.  Look in pg_stat_activity to see what is happening.